# Lambda syntax: elements where a function has a certain value over a range of arguments

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have a custom type `MyType` with a function `MyBoolFunction(string)` that returns true or false.

I have a large list of `MyType` objects `MyTypeList`.

I have a list of string objects `StringList`.

I would like to get the subset of `MyTypeList` where `myTypeList.MyBoolFunction(arg)` is true for at least one value of `arg` as `arg` ranges over `StringList`.

I think I should be able to do this with C# lambda expressions.

I imagine something like this (pseudocode)

```
MyTypeList.Where(x => (x.MyBoolFunction(arg)==true for some arg in StringList);
```

Is this possible?  How can I do this?

Comment: Wow, looks like a lot of us were all typing the same thing at once!  Doh!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
var query = MyTypeList.Where(x => StringList.Any(arg => x.MyBoolFunction(arg)));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MyTypeList.Where(x => StringList.Any(s => x.MyBoolFunction(s)));
```

For some clarity, `s` is an entry in the `StringList` and `x` is an entry in `MyTypeList`

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your actual types i would say:

```
MyTypeList.Where(x => StringList.Any(arg => x.MyBoolFunction(arg));
```

Comment: I think you need one more close parenthesis.